# C Linkage Terminology Differences

Tags: c, linkage

There is static linkage, dynamic linkage.  What is type where it imports compiled functions from a library and compiles it into the binary?

Comment: Maybe you speak of Link-Time Optimization, which is not a linkage thing (but a compiler thing).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_build

Comment: Read Levine's book [Linkers and Loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's actually a reference in the wikipedia article.

Comment: C only knows about internal (static) and external linkage.  The latter is what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In static linking, the compiled functions are stored into the executable or dynamic library (if you're creating one).

In dynamic linking, the compiled function is stored in a separated library (DLL in Windows or shared object in Linux). A small piece if code is added to the executable to load that shared library at runtime and map the public functions and variables within it.